# Angular 2 complex nested routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I am upgrading an Angular 2 app from 2.0.0-beta.0 to 2.4

I have complex routing, with many reused Components that have multiple children; I will give a simplified example:

```
└─Home
  ├─Company
  | ├─Requests
  | └─Users
  |   ├─Subscriptions
  |   | └─Requests
  |   └─Requests
  ├─Users
  | ├─Subscriptions
  | | └─Requests
  | └─Requests
  └─Subscriptions
    └─Requests
```

As you can see, the Users component, and the Subscriptions component (with respective children) are used multiple times, and the Request module is also a child of Users and Company separately.

This was simple in Beta 0, as Components could have their own separate routing. However I have been unable to find a good way to do this in the current version of Angular. I could turn every reused component with children into a module with a  bootstrapped component, but that adds much more code and will not be very flexible.

Is there a way to do this without making each reused component that has children a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by putting this code in each of my components:

in foo.component.ts:

```
import { BarComponent } from './bar.component'
export const FooRouting: Routes = [
    { path: 'Bar', component: BarComponent }
]
```

and in home.ts (the module)

```
import { FooComponent, FooRouting } from './foo.component'
import { BarComponent } from './bar.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: FooComponent, children: FooRouting }
            { path: 'Bar', component: BarComponent }
        ])
        ...
    ],
    ...
)}
```

to make:

```
└─Home
  ├─Foo
  | └─Bar
  └─Bar
```

Answer (score 2):

What about simply using 'children' + 'redirectTo'?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'company', children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: CompanyComponent},
    // path '/company/requests' will redirectTo '/requests'
    { path: 'requests': redirectTo: '/requests' }, 
    { path: 'users': redirectTo: '/users' },
  ]},
  { path: 'users', children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: UsersComponent },
    { path: 'subscriptions', redirectTo: '/subscriptions' },
    { path: 'requests', redirectTo: '/requests' }
  ]},
  { path: 'subscriptions', children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: SubscriptionsComponent },
    { path: 'requests', redirectTo: '/requests' },
  ]},
  { path: 'requests', component: RequestsComponent },
];
```

Comment: I could do this, but where you've got { path: 'users', ...}, the routes would be repeated exactly the same as the first time. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Added a bunch of 'redirectTo'. See if it helps.

Comment: Interesting... Unfortunately I need to keep the path full length, as I have router-outlets nested within router-outlets, and all previous components are still open. It seems I must succumb to the inevitable and just use nested modules.